# What is the difference between Resnet 50 and yolo or rcnn?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

being new to Deep Learning i am struggling to understand the difference between different state of the art algos and their uses. like how is resnet or vgg diff from yolo or rcnn family. are they subcomponents of these detection models? also are SSDs another family like yolo or rcnn?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ResNet is a family of neural networks (using residual functions). A lot of neural network use ResNet architecture, for example:

- ResNet18, ResNet50
- Wide ResNet50
- ResNeSt
- and many more...

It is commonly used as a backbone (also called encoder or feature extractor) for image classification, object detection, object segmentation and many more.
There is others families of nets like VGG, EfficientNets etc...

FasterRCNN/RCN, YOLO and SSD are more like "pipeline" for object detection. For example, FasterRCNN use a backbone for feature extraction (like ResNet50) and a second network called RPN (Region Proposal Network).
Take a look a this [article](https://cv-tricks.com/object-detection/faster-r-cnn-yolo-ssd/) which present the most common "pipeline" for object detection.

Comment: thanks for that. it clears a lot. one thing i need to ask though. i.e feature extraction. my unserstanding is that. extraction of all possible windows for all defined scales of images is feature extraction. am i right?

Comment: What you define is the role of the Region Proposal Network in FasterRCNN. The feature extraction is a dimensionality reduction, for example with ResNet18, if you input an image (ie matrix of size `(3, 224, 224)`) you will get after passing it through the network a vector of size 512. Those 512 numbers are the feature extracted, they define a representation of the image with less numbers.

Comment: ok got it. to sum it up: RPN extract best possible windows from input image then feature extractors extract features from these patches. then extracted features are fed to classifier and so on. yes?

Comment: That's almost the idea but the RPN of FasterRCNN actually use the extracted features to generate windows, then do a ROI Pooling (which is kinda a maxpooling on the windows) and finally fed those pooled features to the classifiers. Take a look at [faster-r-cnn-explained](https://medium.com/@smallfishbigsea/faster-r-cnn-explained-864d4fb7e3f8) for a better understanding/explanation.